# How do I create a new list for every duplicate entry found in a .csv file?

Tags: python

I want a new list called `airport_data` to be created with the information based on how how many entries of that airport appear in a csv file.

I haven't tried anything yet as I am not the best programmer so I genuinely don't know where to start.

```
import csv

def main():
    airportname = input("What airport are you looking for?").upper()

    f1 = open("airports.csv", "r", encoding="utf8")
    if f1.mode == "r":
        csv_f = csv.reader(f1)
        airport_data = []

        for row in csv_f:
            if airportname in row:
                airport_data.append(row[1])#Airport ICAO Code
                airport_data.append(row[3])#Airport Name
        f1.close()

    f2 = open("runways.csv", "r", encoding="utf8")
    if f2.mode == "r":
        csv_f = csv.reader(f2)

        for row in csv_f:
            if airportname in row:
                airport_data.append(row[3])#Runway Length
                airport_data.append(round(float(row[12])))#Runway Heading
                airport_data.append(row[8])#Runway Name
                airport_data.append(row[14])#Opp Runway Name
                airport_data.append(round(float(row[17])))#Airport Elevation
                print(airport_data)      

    print("You have chosen %s (%s). The Airport Elevation is %sft and Runways %s and %s are available"  % (airport_data[1],airport_data[0],airport_data[6],airport_data[4],airport_data[5]))

main()
```

---

```
What airport are you looking for?KLAX
['KLAX', 'Los Angeles International Airport', '8925', 83, '06L', '24R', 117]
['KLAX', 'Los Angeles International Airport', '8925', 83, '06L', '24R', 117, '10285', 83, '06R', '24L', 111]
['KLAX', 'Los Angeles International Airport', '8925', 83, '06L', '24R', 117, '10285', 83, '06R', '24L', 111, '12091', 83, '07L', '25R', 94]
['KLAX', 'Los Angeles International Airport', '8925', 83, '06L', '24R', 117, '10285', 83, '06R', '24L', 111, '12091', 83, '07L', '25R', 94, '11096', 83, '07R', '25L', 95]
You have chosen Los Angeles International Airport (KLAX). The Airport Elevation is 117ft and Runways 06L and 24R are available.
```

I want it to be something like:

```
['KLAX', 'Los Angeles International Airport', '8925', 83, '06L', '24R', 117]
['KLAX', 'Los Angeles International Airport', '10285', 83, '06R', '24L', 111]
['KLAX', 'Los Angeles International Airport', '12091', 83, '07L', '25R', 94]
['KLAX', 'Los Angeles International Airport', '11096', 83, '07R', '25L', 95]
```

Comment: Why are you testing `f1.mode`? Why would it be different from the mode that you requested in `open()`?

Comment: Why is airport elevation in the runway file?

Comment: create a new list inside your runways loop

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of `airport_data` each time through the second loop. I've called this `runway_data`.

Also, you should break out of the first loop once you find the airport you're looking for.

```
import csv

def main():
    airportname = input("What airport are you looking for?").upper()

    with open("airports.csv", "r", encoding="utf8") as f1:
        csv_f = csv.reader(f1)
        airport_data = []

        for row in csv_f:
            if airportname in row:
                airport_data.append(row[1])#Airport ICAO Code
                airport_data.append(row[3])#Airport Name
                break

    with open("runways.csv", "r", encoding="utf8") as f2:
        csv_f = csv.reader(f2)
        for row in csv_f:
            if airportname in row:
                runway_data = airport_data[:] # Copy airport data to runway
                runway_data.append(row[3])#Runway Length
                runway_data.append(round(float(row[12])))#Runway Heading
                runway_data.append(row[8])#Runway Name
                runway_data.append(row[14])#Opp Runway Name
                runway_data.append(round(float(row[17])))#Airport Elevation
                print(runway_data)      

    print("You have chosen %s (%s). The Airport Elevation is %sft and Runways %s and %s are available"  % (airport_data[1],airport_data[0],runway_data[0][6],runway_data[0][4],runway_data[0][5]))

main()
```